# jquery implicit binding to this

Tags: jquery

I looked through other same title postings but I did not see explanation(or maybe they were not same question as far as I can see) that helped me see what's going on).

So basically, what I understand well is the implicit binding where if you use something.func, then 'this' is set to 'something'.

Now, I am sort of jumping into jquery and see something like below

```
$("button").click(user.clickHandler);
```

I thought user.clickHandler would make 'user' as this when clickHandler was invoked but chrome developer shows me that it's not(it's button is set to 'this'). And I understand I need to use bind to specify the 'user'.
Why is this the case? I thought I understand implicit binding fine in javascript. I am just not sure how to read this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Get Random Person</button>
    <input type="text">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script>
    var user = {
         data : [
        {name: "T.Woods", age:37},
       {name:"P.Mickelson", age:43}
    ],
        clickHandler:function(event){
            var randomNum = ( (Math.random () * 2|0) +1) -1; // random
           $("input").val(this.data[randomNum].name + " " + this.data[randomNum].age);
        }
    }    

    $("button").click(user.clickHandler);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this` is the button the handler is attached to with the `apply` from the click handler here.

Comment: I am digging deeper into this as I am still not satisfied. I see that $("button") in this case is basically 'this'.. I am not 100% sure where in doc says that that is the case. I will be back on this

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery dispatches events (see the `jQuery.event.trigger` function in the jQuery code), it uses [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to bind the element receiving the event to `this`.

I suggest you replace

```
$("button").click(user.clickHandler);
```

by

```
$("button").click(function(e) {user.clickHandler(e);});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery.proxy( function, context [, additionalArguments ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

```
$("button").click($.proxy(user.clickHandler, user));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Get Random Person</button>
  <input type="text">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script>
    var user = {
      data: [{
        name: "T.Woods",
        age: 37
      }, {
        name: "P.Mickelson",
        age: 43
      }],
      clickHandler: function(event) {
        console.log(this, event);
        var randomNum = ((Math.random() * 2 | 0) + 1) - 1; // random
        $("input").val(this.data[randomNum].name + " " + this.data[randomNum].age);
      }
    }
    $("button").click($.proxy(user.clickHandler, user));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry i am actually looking for why initially it work the way it does

Comment: _"am actually looking for why initially it work the way it does"_ See Answer by @PatrickFournier http://stackoverflow.com/a/34389457/ , source of jQuery `.click()` https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: And to get the button reference use `event.target` thus `alert($(event.target).text());` alerts "Get Random Person"